# Pandas apply, but access previously calculated value

Tags: python, pandas, apply, shift

Suppose I have a DataFrame (or Series) like this:

```
     Value
0    0.5
1    0.8
2    -0.2
3    None
4    None
5    None
```

I wish to create a new **Result** column.

The value of each result is determined by the **previous** Value, via an arbitrary function `f`.

If the previous Value is not available (None or NaN), I wish to use instead the **previous Result** (and apply `f` to it, of course).

---

Using the previous Value is easy, I just need to use `shift`. However, accessing the previous result doesn't seem to be that simple.

For example, the following code calculates the result, but cannot access the previous result if needed.

```
df['Result'] = df['Value'].shift(1).apply(f)
```

Please assume that `f` is arbitrary, and thus solutions using things like `cumsum` are not possible.

---

Obviously, this can be done by iteration, but I want to know if a more Panda-y solution exists.

```
df['Result'] = None
for i in range(1, len(df)):
  value = df.iloc[i-1, 'Value']
  if math.isnan(value) or value is None:
    value = df.iloc[i-1, 'Result']
  df.iloc[i, 'Result'] = f(value)
```

---

Example output, given `f = lambda x: x+1`:

Bad:

```
   Value    Result
0    0.5       NaN
1    0.8       1.5
2   -0.2       1.8
3    NaN       0.8
4    NaN       NaN
5    NaN       NaN
```

Good:

```
   Value    Result
0    0.5       NaN
1    0.8       1.5
2   -0.2       1.8
3    NaN       0.8
4    NaN       1.8   <-- previous Value not available, used f(previous result)
5    NaN       2.8   <-- same
```

Comment: How about `df['Result'] = df['Value'].shift(1).apply(f).ffill()`?

Comment: @IanS the values filled by `ffill` will not have `f` applied to them.

Comment: Edited body to clarify the above

Comment: Been looking around a lot for a non-loop answer to this question. I really feel like the `apply()` lambda function should have some capability similar to `shift`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it has to be a loop to me.  And I abhor loops... so when I loop, I use `numba`

> Numba gives you the power to speed up your applications with high performance functions written directly in Python. With a few annotations, array-oriented and math-heavy Python code can be just-in-time compiled to native machine instructions, similar in performance to C, C++ and Fortran, without having to switch languages or Python interpreters.

https://numba.pydata.org/

```
from numba import njit


@njit
def f(x):
    return x + 1

@njit
def g(a):
    r = [np.nan]
    for v in a[:-1]:
        if np.isnan(v):
            r.append(f(r[-1]))
        else:
            r.append(f(v))
    return r

df.assign(Result=g(df.Value.values))

   Value  Result
0    0.5     NaN
1    0.8     1.5
2   -0.2     1.8
3    NaN     0.8
4    NaN     1.8
5    NaN     2.8
```

Answer (score 0):

This might fit into pandas coding style. However, efficiency-wise, I think further test is required. This is not applicable to general functions. This 
 somehow tricked the plus 1 function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[0.5,0.8,-0.2,None,None,None]})
index = df['Value'].index[df['Value'].apply(np.isnan)]
window = max(index)-min(index)+1
df['next'] =df['Value'].shift(1)


def getX(x):
    last = np.where(~np.isnan(x))[0][-1]
    return (x[last])+len(x)-last



df['plus_one'] = df['next'].rolling(window=3,min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: getX(x))
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `f` is an arbitrary function, it could have been `math.sin` for example, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work, but I'm not sure. It stores the previously calculated value in a closure.

```
def use_previous_if_none(f):
    prev = None
    def wrapped(val):
        nonlocal prev
        if math.isnan(val) or val is None:
                val = prev
        res = f(val)
        prev = res
        return res
    return wrapped

df['Result'] = df.Value.shift(1).apply(use_previous_if_none(f))
```

Comment: @piRSquared thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a solution without explicit loops. Instead of referencing previous value, it `ffil()'s` the `NaNs` and then apply `f` as many time as required only on the values that were at indeces of `NaNs`.

We start by defining help function that will call `f` `n` times:

```
def apply_f_n_times(arg):
    x = arg[0]
    n = int(arg[1])
    for i in range(n):
        x = f(x)
    return x

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 2, 3, 5, None, None, 12, 9, None, 6, 1, None, None, None]})
df['Result'] = df['Value'].shift(1).apply(f)
# the following 2 lines will create counter of consecutive NaNs 
tmp = df['Result'].isnull()
df['Apply_times'] = tmp * (tmp.groupby((tmp != tmp.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1)
# fill NaNs with previous good value 
df['Result'] = df['Result'].ffill()
# apply N times
df['Result'] = df[['Result', 'Apply_times']].apply(apply_f_n_times, axis=1)
```

The result:

```
Out[2]:
      Value  Result  Apply_times
0     1.0     nan            1
1     2.0     2.0            0
2     3.0     3.0            0
3     5.0     4.0            0
4     nan     6.0            0
5     nan     7.0            1
6    12.0     8.0            2
7     9.0    13.0            0
8     nan    10.0            0
9     6.0    11.0            1
10    1.0     7.0            0
11    nan     2.0            0
12    nan     3.0            1
13    nan     4.0            2
```