# Speeding up a row operation that uses the result of previous rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, numba

I have some data from an accelorometer where I try to smooth the values out. The problem I'm having is that my data frame contains approx. 1,000,000 rows and running the *smoothing* function seen below therefore takes several minutes (I'm running it in jupyter)

```
def smoothing(df, alpha, length):
    df['x'][0] = df['x'][0] * alpha

    for i in range(1,length):
        df['x'][i] = df['x'][i-1]+alpha*(df['x'][i] - df['x'][i-1])

    return df
```

My question is if there is anyway to enhance or speed up this computation by using vectorization, pandas.apply, or similar. Please note that I've tried using these approaches myself but without any luck as I fail to produce the correct result. The part I'm struggling with is getting the result of the previous rows and I'm unsure how to e.g. use .shift() to get the same functionality as in the *smoothing* function

Here is some sample data:

```
x_list = [21,42,49,8,0,-57,-137, -135,-177, -181]
data = pd.DataFrame(x_list, columns=['x'])
smoothing(data, 0.02, len(x_list))
```

Expected result:

```
    x
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5  -1
6  -3
7  -5
8  -8
9 -11
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of that 'some data' and its expected output?

Comment: Cant you post the same in the form of text please. We cant copy images. Also the expected output.

Comment: `(df['x'][i] - df['x'])` ? This will return an entrire column. Is that a typo ?

Comment: What value of alpha are you using? What is your expected output for this data?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ as soon as the OP posts the expected output we will see who's faster ohk .

Comment: @Bharathshetty Hmm, I'll let you take this one :-)

Comment: I'm not in a position to answer this question but if you need to loop, consider numba. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46422228/2336654

Comment: @piRSquared i'll try this ty, however I would rather not loop if possible

Comment: This looks like exponential smoothing. If so, pandas has built-in support for this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html

Comment: @ayhan ty i'll take a look at that, however im more interested in how to generally solve this problem of using the previous rows in .apply) or similar since im constructing a complementary filter aswell where the loop structure is similar

Comment: You cannot solve this without loops. Your function is recursive so one way or another you need the result of a previously calculated value. This cannot be done with pandas' or numpy's vectorized operations. You pass a vector and in return you get a vector. Your resulting vector cannot be a function of the resulting vector. Like I said, you may have a chance with specialized cases like ewm but there is no general solution for this.

Comment: Actually, I figured this out. One, your formula is wrong in that x0 does not get alpha times x0. It is just x0. Two, your formula can be changed to the form: (1-alpha) * x[i-1] + alpha * x[i]. I can give you a vectorized form of this but that would be silly as this is just an exponential weighted average. Use df.x.ewm(alpha=alpha).mean()

Comment: @piRSquared ty for all your help. If u don't mind i would like to see how to solve this using vectorization, I might find myself in a similar situation in the future where i can't use som build in function.

Comment: @piRSquared Actually that's the trick. It is not `(1-alpha) * x[i-1] + alpha * x[i]`; it is `(1-alpha) * f(x[i-1]) + alpha * x[i]`. So you cannot use `shift`, for example.

Comment: @ayhan yep. I get it. I'm doing stuff with family and can't do much other than comment. I'll say that f in this case is linear and can be "bundled". In fact it already is with the df.x.emw(alpha=alpha).mean()

Comment: @piRSquared thats ewm :)

Comment: @piRSquared You mean something like [this](http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411avg_files/image028.png) right? I guess that method has some floating accuracy problems. I'd expect pandas to code this with a straight loop in cython but didn't check. Anyway, let me leave you to your family. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apply with help of a global variable to store the calcuated value to get your desired output i.e

```
store = 0
def m(x):
    global store 
    if x == data['x'][0]:
        store = 0.2*x
        return store
    else :     
        store = (store+alpha*(x - store))
        return store    

data['x'].apply(m)
```

Output:

```
0     4.200000
1    11.760000
2    19.208000
3    16.966400
4    13.573120
5    -0.541504
6   -27.833203
7   -49.266563
8   -74.813250
9   -96.050600
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

```
%%timeit
data['x'].apply(m)
1000 loops, best of 3: 478 µs per loop

n = pd.concat([data['x']]*10000).reset_index(drop=True) # in function condtion shld be n[0] instead of data['x'][0]
n.apply(m)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.18 s per loop
```

Comment: @i regular I suggest not to accept answer soon. There will be great answers coming by and I fell bad when you dont accept those answer just because you selected mine.

Comment: expanding.apply has O(n!) complexity. This would take hours for a mid-sized array.

Comment: @ayhan I just put the solution to just get the expected output. Will try to improve now. I wanted to be first to post the solution haha :)

Comment: my comment was directed more towards the OP since they are not convinced this cannot be vectorized. :)

Comment: Since its cumulative along with a condition you are right not every for loop is meant to be vectorized :)

Comment: Btw, I think `if x == data['x'][0]:` is quite computationally costly (simply b/c `if` statements generally are) and could actually give a wrong answer if you have a duplicate value in column x.  Probably better to do something like `data.loc[1:,'x'].apply(m)` and alter the function accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the numba way, which is quite a bit faster than the function in the OP (about 20,000x faster for 10,000 rows, and that's not a typo!):

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def smoothing_numba(x,alpha):
    x[0] = x[0] * alpha

    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i-1] + alpha * ( x[i] - x[i-1] )

    return x

smoothing_numba(data.x.values,0.02)
```

If you left the `@njit` decorator out of the above code you'd have a standard numpy function.  This turns out to be about 150x slower than numba, but still 150x faster than the original function.

Here are the timings at 10,000 rows.

```
np.random.seed(123)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000), columns=['x'])

%timeit smoothing(data, 0.02, len(data))
1 loop, best of 3: 995 ms per loop

%timeit smoothing_numba(data.x.values, 0.02)
10000 loops, best of 3: 41.8 µs per loop
```

In cases like this where a loop is unavoidable, it is certainly not unusual to see a significant speedup from converting a pandas function to a numpy/numba function.  Also note that numba is designed to play well with numpy so once you have converted the function from pandas to numpy it is generally trivial to decorate with `@njit` for addition speed.

Comment: I will for sure use this in the future ty. I can confirm that I get almost similar timings